# how to add text rather than replacing it in textfields java

Tags: java, swing, replace, append, addition

I have multiple buttons containing some information.
Now I want that the information written on the buttons are appended when i press them i.e when i press the first button 
- the information gets printed into text field
When I press second button 
- the information written on button gets appended or added into the text field with the older information (data in button 1).

code for what I am trying is:

```
private void EActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEventevt) {                                  
   String x = ans.getText();
   for(int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
      ans.setText("H");
   }
}

private void FActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                  
    String x = ans.getText();
    for(int i = 0; i > x.length(); i++) {
         ans.setText("A");
         System.out.println("completed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply:

```
ans.setText(ans.getText() + newString);
```

Comment: Given that DocumentEvents are generated whenever you change the Document you really should just update the Document with the new text (as demonstrated by MadProgrammers answer) rather than replace the existing text otherwise you get incorrect events generated.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to this, `setText` is one, but it's not particularly efficient (it's easier to type though), as you are creating additional temporary objects though the process

If you need to update the field often, you might consider using something more like...

```
Document doc = userNameField.getDocument();
doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), newString, null);
```